# Wget for puppet installation

Tags: wget

I'm going to install puppet (puppet master) in a CentOs v7 Server which is running on google cloud. I am facing a issue with downloading the puppet tarball into my server.

Once I use below command,

```
wget https://pm.puppet.com/cgi-bin/download.cgi?arch=x86_64&dist=el&rel=7&ver=latest
```

It is downloding the .CGI file. not the Tar ball. But once I hit the url it download the respective tar file

Comment: It does not work because ? and & are special characters to the shell,  and need to be escaped. Keep it in mind for future similar problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try quotes on the URL?

For me this command starts to download 472MB of puppet-enterprise-2018.1.4-el-7-x86_64.tar.gz

```
wget -O puppet-enterprise-2018.1.4-el-7-x86_64.tar.gz 'https://pm.puppet.com/cgi-bin/download.cgi?arch=x86_64&dist=el&rel=7&ver=latest'
```

If that doesn't help, then there are probably some cookies needed. If you have SSH access to the machine, download the file to your local machine and use `scp` to copy it to the remote machine.

Comment: Thanks, It worked after adding quotes on the URL. And I was thinking to do it in second way with SCP option. How ever it worked with quotes, Somehow I missed to add, Thanks !!